# Changing a UIImageView image with a slider

Tags: objective-c

I have a view with one UIImageView and a slider. Slider Min 1 Max 10. When slider is moved UIImageView should display a different image. Slider is 1 test1.png will display, slider is 2 test2.png will display, slider is 3 test3.png will display etc...

In Interface Builder I have connected IBOutlet slider to Horizontal slider, IBOutlet image to Image View, & IBAction changeImage to Horizontal slider "Value Changed"

I've cast slider float to int. Placed an NSLog statement in IBAction changeImage to make sure method is being called, It is. I receive no error messages on build. However, when i build & Run and move slider in simulator image in UIImageView does not change. The problem must be "logic" I've hit a wall and can not figure it out.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SliderViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;

- (IBAction)changeImage;

@end



#import "SliderViewController.h"

@implementation SliderViewController


@synthesize slider;
@synthesize image;


- (IBAction)changeImage {

    NSLog(@"changeImage method being called!!!!");

    int intSlider = (int)(slider.value);


    if (intSlider == 0) {


                image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash1.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 1) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash2.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 2) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash3.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 3) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash4.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 4) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash5.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 5) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash6.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 6) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash7.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 7) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash8.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 8) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash9.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 9) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash10.png"];
    }

    if (intSlider == 10) {


        image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ash11.png"];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image names are exactly right and that you've actually Added them to the project (not just copied them using Finder).

By the way, a `switch-case` statement would be better than a series of `if-then` statements here.

Another minor thing is that the `if (intSlider == 0)` case will never happen since you're setting the minimum to 1.

Answer (score 0):

According to the forums one method would be to try calling setNeedsDisplay to refresh the view:

```
myApp = (MyApp *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[myApp.statView setNeedsDisplay];
```

I'm sure you could just call this on 'self' from your view.

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

According to [this post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4475-howto-refresh-content-uiview-subclass.html) the call has to be in the main thread of the app as well.  Not sure this will work, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

**changing image using  valued slider in objective c**

**.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sldrimg;


- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender;
```

**.m**

```
- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender {

    int a = (int) self.sldrimg.value;
    if(a<=20)
    {
        _imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nature.png"];
    }


    if(a>20 && a<=40)
    {
        _imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bike.png"];
    }


    if(a>40 && a<=60)
    {
        _imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"minion.png"];
    }


    if(a>60 && a<=80)
    {
        _imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"woods.png"];
    }


    if(a>80 && a<=100)
    {
        _imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trees.png"];
    }
```